# How do I create button that returns to "hidden" data onclick in js, that was previously input by user?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**How do I create button that returns to "hidden" data onclick in js, that was previously input by user?**

```html
<html>
<script>
  var input,
    inputCount = 0;

function newInput () {
  if (input !== undefined) {
    input.type = "hidden";  
  }
  inputCount++;
  
  input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.name = input.placeholder = "fname" + inputCount;
  document.getElementById("box").appendChild(input);
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="newInput()">Add Property</button><br/>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <br/><span id="box"></span><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use jQuery in your programs. It'll make your life so much easier

```
<button type="button" class="hiding-button">Add Property</button>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".hiding-button").on("click",function(){
        newInput();
        $(this).hide();
    });
</script>
```